# NoClassDefFoundError on a protocol when requiring its namespace

Tags: java, spring, interop, clojure, classloader

This is the recipe for the exception I'm getting (EDIT: `ProtoImpl` is defined in another ns, I'll leave it out to ease the description):

**myns.clj**

```
(ns myns)

(defprotocol Proto
  (func [this]))

(extend-protocol Proto
  ProtoImpl
  (func [this] (do-something ...)))
```

**interop.clj**

```
(ns interop
  (:require [myns :as m]))

(defn startup
  []
  (m/func (ProtoImpl.)))

(gen-class :name interop.Interop
           :prefix "interop-"
           :methods [[boot [] void]])

(defn interop-boot
  [this]
  (startup)))
```

Both myns.clj and interop.clj are shipped within a webapp, the latter being also AOT compiled thus produging Interop.class available in the classpath right away. This is instantiated as a Spring bean.

When the webapp starts, it fails to bootstrap with the following exception:

```
[...]
    at myns__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at myns__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[...]
    at interop.Interop.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[...]
Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: myns.Proto
```

What can cause this issue?

---

**EDIT:** I cannot reproduce the error anymore, I recompiled and re-run the application, which started up flawlessly... Still I would really like to understand in which situations such an issue can show up.

It looks to me like the class loader couldn't find the class definition for `Proto`, which I assume is the role of clojure RT to load as soon as the relevant .clj source file is parsed. As you can see in the extract of the stack trace I receive, myns is being loaded, and it it exactly there that `Proto` is defined. How come I got a `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure Records are supposed to be imported. The following should work:

```
(ns interop
  (:require [myns :as m])
  (:import  myns.Proto))
```

Comment: There's no direct reference to `Proto` inside the `interop` namespace, why should I `:import` it?

Comment: besides, the exception is a `NoClassDefFoundError`, meaning the class loader couldn't find the .class definition for Proto. If the problem was that I forgot to `import` the protocol, I would expect something like `java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: Proto in this context (interop.clj:<...>)`

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, and even though the answer is not directly related to the question it's always worth it to point out what's needed to use a Prototype in Clojure, I just accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Adding both classes to `:aot` in my `project.clj` resolved the issue. Your `project.clj` would have something like this: `:aot [myns interop]`.